# Given 8 People in a race including Alice and Bob. How many ranked lists of these people see Alice ahead of Bob?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This was an exam question on a paper I sat today.

My solution was something like this.

- Number of ways of arranging 8 unique things is 8!
- There is a 50% chance Bob beats Alice and a 50% chance Alice beats Bob.
- Therefore 8! / 2 is the number of combinations / ranked lists.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are ties between racers a possibility?

Comment: @DanielSchepler this wasn't something I thought of. I don't, however, believe that it was a possibility.

Comment: Your answer is correct. But when you say "There is a 50% chance Bob beats Alice and a 50% chance Alice beats Bob." sounds like weird. You may say "We can separate the $8!$ exactly two distinct parts one of them Alice ahead of Bob and the other one Bob ahead of Alice. And the parts has same elements..."

Comment: @S.S.Danyal thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the long answer with all the stuations.

1. Alice is first. Then put Bob to the one of the 7 rooms. And put other guys the other 6 rooms. Then we get $7.6!$
2. Alice is second. Then put Bob to the one of the 6 rooms.  And put other guys the other 6 rooms. Then we get $6.6!$
3. Alice is third. Then put Bob to the one of the 5 rooms.  And put other guys the other 6 rooms. Then we get $5.6!$

...

6. Alice is 6-th. Then put Bob to the one of the 2 rooms.  And put other guys the other 6 rooms. Then we get $2.6!$.
7. Alice is 7-th. Then put Bob to the last room.  And put other guys the other 6 rooms. Then we get $1.6!$.

Total sum $7.6!+6.6!+\ldots+1.6!=6!(7+6+\ldots+1)=6!.\frac{7.8}{2}=\frac{8!}{2}$.